# Why I can't successfully subtract two datetime values in php?

Tags: php, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have the following code:

```
echo "first row " . $firstRow["begin_date"];
echo " super beg " . $superbegintime; 
echo " duration " . $duration;
if(($firstRow["begin_date"] - $superbegintime) >= $duration)
{
    echo "it works!";
}
```

`$firstRow["begin_date"]` is a `DATETIME` type field taken from database

`$superbegintime` is created as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$superbegintime= $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('10 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and `$duration` is a field `$duration = 15;` that should represent number of seconds.

I cannot enter the if statement and print the `it works!` message, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `$duration`?

Comment: @JohnConde  `$duration = 15;`

Comment: Minutes? Days? Months?

Comment: It's just a number to be honest, I want this to stand for seconds though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing and doing math with strings which can be problematic and not get  you the right results especially when you compare them to integers (and don't specify what that number actually means). DateTime objects allow you to do the math and then compare the difference with the duration. The difference and the duration are both DateInterval objects which are comparable.

```
$beginDate      = new DateTime($firstRow["begin_date"]);
$superbegintime = new DateTime($superbegintime); 
$duration       = DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 seconds');
$diff = $beginDate->diff($superbegintime);

if($diff >= $duration)
{
    echo "it works!";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/448389)

Comment: Thanks a lot, however when I used your code I'm getting the following error `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'createFromDateString' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in ...` but since it works in your demo - what might be the problem on my side?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.6.12

Comment: I'm using a version less than 5.6 and it works. @randomuser3 You sure you copied John's code exactly? Something doesn't pan out here. Might be what's coming from your DB that DateTime() doesn't agree with.

Comment: I did have a syntax error I corrected. Maybe you still have it? If the word `new` is right before `DateInterval` remove it.

Comment: Ok guys sorry, my bad, now everything works fine, I had to probably copied not everything correctly..